# How do you reduce the time needed for `pod install` with Cocoapods for a project with many dependencies?

Tags: cocoapods

My project has about 60 dependencies, listed one after another...

```
platform :ios, '7.1'

inhibit_all_warnings! # This will disable all the warnings for all pods!

target 'MyProj' do
  pod 'First'
  pod 'Second'
  ...  # 57 more pods
  pod 'Last'
end
```

Every `pod install` takes about 3-4 minutes.

When trying to restructure the project in to smaller pods, it takes hours and hours to change extract the relevant dependencies into private pods and it is very expensive to iterate.

How can I work on Podfiles and splitting application modules up more effectively?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the bottleneck that is happening you can try running `pod install` and telling CocoaPods not to update the specs repo:

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

Note that this will cause issue if you add a new version of a pod that has not been downloaded locally let in which case you'll want to run:

```
pod repo update
```

Comment: Running it with `--verbose` may also give you a clue about _where_ the slowness is coming from.

Comment: Also, using git tags is faster than git commit references